# Why are class slots specified with keywords but accessed with symbols?

Tags: oop, syntax, common-lisp

I have recently encountered a confusing dichotomy regarding structures in Lisp.

When creating a structure with `(defstruct)`, we specify the slots by keyword (`:slotname`). But when accessing it, we use local symbols (`'slotname`).

**Why? This makes no sense to me.**

Also, doesn't this pollute the `keyword` package every time you declare a structure?

If I try to access the slots by keyword, I get confusing errors like:

> When attempting to read the slot's value (slot-value), the slot :BALANCE is
> missing from the object #S(ACCOUNT :BALANCE 1000 :CUSTOMER-NAME "John Doe").

I don't understand this message. It seems to be telling me that something right under my nose doesn't exist.

I have tried declaring the structure using local symbols; and also with unbound keywords (`#:balance`) and these don't work.

Comment: you need to come up with an actual example. In standard Common Lisp structure slots are not accessed via slotnames, but via functions.

Comment: `(slot-value 'balance some-object)`

Comment: I didn't even know until today that structures *had* implicit accessor functions. I've been using `(slot-value)` for months. So, my question is simply, why doesn't `(slot-value :balance some-object)` work?

Comment: whether SLOT-VALUE works at all with structure objects is explicitly unspecified in the Common Lisp standard. Your example also makes no sense, since the arguments to the function SLOT-VALUE are wrong. First comes an object, then the slot name.

Comment: Fine! `(slot-value object 'balance)`. We've nit-picked, but we're no closer to an answer to my question. Which was, in case you've forgotten, **why keywords in the definition but symbols in the usage?**

Comment: as I already mentioned, the behavior is unspecified anyway

Comment: Also, the responses to my question seem to indicate that `(with-slots)` is unsuitable for structs, AND unsuitable for classes. So what, pray, do you claim it *is* suitable for?

Comment: WITH-SLOTS is defined for CLOS classes.

Comment: @SodAlmighty: that's a style question.  Many people use accessors for public interfaces and slot names for internal ones I suspect.  For things defined with `defstruct` there are only accessors, but you can assume the accessors are extremely fast (you can't, say, define methods on them).

Answer (score 5):

`DEFSTRUCT` is designed in the language standard in this way:

- slot-names are not exposed
- there is no specified way to get a list of slot-names of a structure class
- there is no specified way to access a slot via a slot-name
- thus at runtime there might be no slot-names
- access to slots is optimized with accessor functions: static structure layout, inlined accessor functions, ...

Also explicitly:

- slot-names are not allowed to be duplicate under `string=`. Thus slots `foo::a` and `bar::a` in the same structure class are not allowed
- the effects of redefining a structure is undefined

The goal of structures is to provide fast record-like objects without costly features like redefinition, multiple inheritance, etc.

Thus using `SLOT-VALUE` to access structure slots is an extension of implementations, not a part of the defined language. `SLOT-VALUE` was introduced when CLOS was added to Common Lisp. Several implementations provide a way to access a structure slot via `SLOT-VALUE`. This then also requires that the implementation has kept track of slot names of that structure.

`SLOT-VALUE` is simply a newer API function, coming from CLOS for CLOS. Structures are an older feature, which was defined already in the first version of Common Lisp defined by the book CLtL1.

Comment: I did not know these things. Thank you for the concise breakdown.

Comment: So, what I'm seeing here is that `(with-slots)` has "undefined behaviour" on structs, but "happens to work" in SBCL. So, can I continue using it in SBCL? Or, is it better (and feasible) to write a macro `(with-struct-slots)` that emits a `(let ((balance (account-balance instance) ... )`-type construct?

Answer (score 3):

You used `make-instance` to create a class instance and then you are showing a struct, I am confused.

structs automatically build their accessor functions. You create it with `make-account`. Then you'd use `account-balance` instead of `slot-value`.

I don't know what is the expected behavior to use `make-instance` with a struct. While it seemed to work on my SBCL, you are not using structs right.

```lisp
(defstruct account 
   (balance))

(make-account :balance 100)
#S(ACCOUNT :BALANCE 100)

(account-balance *)
100
```

With classes, you are free to name your accessor functions as you want.

```lisp
;;(pseudocode)
(defclass bank-account () 
  ((balance :initform nil ;; otherwise it's unbound
            :initarg :balance ;; to use with make-instance :balance
            :accessor balance  ;; or account-balance, as you wish.
)))

(make-instance 'bank-account :balance 200)
#<BANK-ACCOUNT {1009302A33}>

(balance *)
200
```

- https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#structures
- http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm

---

> the slot :BALANCE is missing from the object #S(ACCOUNT :BALANCE 1000 :CUSTOMER-NAME "John Doe").

The slot name is actually `balance` and the representation uses the generated initargs. With the class object, the error message might be less confusing:

> When attempting to read the slot's value (slot-value), the slot :BALANCE is missing from the object #<BANK-ACCOUNT {1009302A33}>.

Comment: My issue is primarily with `(defstruct)`. I have edited the question to avoid muddying the issue with classes.

Comment: Wait, `(defstruct)` creates accessor functions for every field? I didn't know that. Is there any way to alter this behaviour?

Comment: Yes it creates accessor functions, and a creator function! You can ask for another creator function (see the Cookbook), but AFAIK there is no way to prevent the creation of accessor functions. In CLOS you can.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see [Rainer's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67225078/5920214) on structures.  In summary:

> Objects defined with `defstruct` have named *accessor functions*, not named slots.  Further the field names of these objects which are mentioned in the `defstruct` form must be distinct *as strings*, and so keywords are completely appropriate for use in constructor functions.  Any use of `slot-value` on such objects is implementation-dependent, and indeed whether or not named slots exist at all is entirely implementation-dependent.

You generally want keyword arguments for the constructors for the reasons you want keyword arguments elsewhere: you don't want to have to painfully provide 49 optional arguments so you can specify the 50th.  So it's reasonable that the default thing `defstruct` does is that. But you can completely override this if you want to, using a BOA constructor, which `defstruct` allows you to do.  You can even have no constructor at all!  As an example here is a rather perverse structure constructor: it does use keyword arguments, but not the ones you might naively expect.

```
(defstruct (foo
            (:constructor
             make-foo (&key ((:y x) 1) ((:x y) 2))))
  y
  x)
```

So the real question revolves around classes defined with `defclass`, which usually *do* have named slots and where `slot-value` does work.

So in this case there are really two parts to the annswer.

Firstly, as before, keyword arguments are *really useful* for constructors because no-one wants to have to remember 932 optional argument defaults.  But `defclass` provides complete control over the mapping between keyword arguments and the slots they initialise, or whether they initialise slots at all or instead are passed to some `initialize-instance` method.  You can just do anything you want here.

Secondly, you *really* want slot names for objects of classes defined with `defclass` to be symbols which live in packages.  You definitely do not want this to happen:

```
(in-package "MY-PACKAGE")
(use-package "SOMEONE-ELSES-PACKAGE")

(defclass my-class (someone-elses-class)
  ((internal-implementation-slot ...)))
```

only to discover that you have just modified the definition of the `someone-elses-package::internal-implementation-slot` slot in `someone-elses-class`.  That would be bad.  So slot names are symbols which live in packages and the normal namespace control around packages works for them too: `my-package::internal-implementation-slot` and `someone-elses-package::internal-implementation-slot` are not (usually) the same thing.

Additionally, the whole keyword-symbol-argument / non-keyword-symbol-variable thing is, well, let's just say well-established:

```
(defun foo (&key (x 1))
  ... x ...)
```

---

Finally note, of course, that keyword arguments don't actually have to be keywords: it's generally convenient that they are because you need quotes otherwise, but:

```
(defclass silly ()
  ((foo :initarg foo
        :accessor silly-foo)
   (bar :initarg bar
        :accessor silly-bar)))
```

And now

```
> (silly-foo (make-instance 'silly 'bar 3 'foo 9))
9
```

Comment: So.....let me see if I have this right. The slots in a struct are actually internally named using symbols, not keywords. That is, if they're internally named *at all*. The same for classes. So when you `(make-thing)`, you can use either keywords or symbols, because the constructor looks up the slot by its string representation. But when you `(slot-value)`, you must use local symbols because the internal slot names are not keywords?

Comment: In which case, why does `(make-thing)` use the string representation, but `(slot-value)` demand the exact symbol?

Comment: @SodAlmighty: I don't think I can help you, sorry.